# Условие с присваиванием

Tags: c++

Программа выводит количество букв и слов. Почему, если  ch = _getche() вынести из условия цикла в его тело, то в cout нужно указывать не chcount a (chcount - 1)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int chcount = 0;
    int wdcount = 1;
    char ch = 'a';
    cout << "Enter the line: ";

    while ((ch = _getche()) != '\r')
    {
        if (ch == ' ')
            wdcount++;
        else
            chcount++;
    }

    cout << "\nWords: " << wdcount << endl;
    cout << "Letters: " << chcount << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как именно вы выносите его в тело?...

Comment: @Harry После скобки, перед if

Comment: Ну а что остается в `while`? Просто сравнение?

Comment: Нет. ch =! '\r'. Вот что будет в while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы вместо

```
while ((ch = _getche()) != '\r')
{
    if (ch == ' ')
        wdcount++;
    else
        chcount++;
}
```

делаете

```
while (ch != '\r')
{
    ch = _getche();
    if (ch == ' ')
        wdcount++;
    else
        chcount++;
}
```

В первом случае считанный `'\r'` вы не считаете (тело цикла не выполняется), во втором - считаете...

Comment: Не понимаю, вы имеете в виду что '\r' считается за символ во втором случае?

Comment: Очередной считанный символ - `\r`. Если он считан в условии (первый вариант), условие нарушено, вы вышли из цикла. Если он считан в теле, вы увеличиваете `chcount` (это не пробел), возвращаетесь к проверке условия цикла, выходите из цикла. Разница понятна? В первом случае тело цикла не выполняется, во втором - выполняется.